# Angle brackets on Spanish keyboard?

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm using a Latin American Spanish keyboard on Windows 8.1 and I need angle brackets (<,>) for writing code. Any suggestions other than using character map?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use Unicode input and input the Unicode value for the characters in question.

Comment: I looked all over, but could not find out how to do that. Any recommendations on how to?